# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - Though No Mismatch found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am try to do a simple insertion in a table but I am getting the following error:
**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**. I know this error drops in if the no of parameters and matches are not same, but I have checked it over and over again and I was not able to find any such mismatch.

I have
 No of Columns in the table: 16
 No of parameters : 16
 No of matches : 16

**The Table description:**

```
mysql> describe faculty;
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| faculty_id            | varchar(8)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| faculty_name          | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| department_id         | varchar(8)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| department_name       | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| profile_pic           | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| designation           | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| doj                   | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email                 | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| highest_qualification | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| industrial_exp_yr     | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| industrial_exp_month  | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| teaching_exp_yr       | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| teaching_exp_month    | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| area_of_interest      | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| national_pub          | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| international_pub     | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

16 rows in set (0.01 sec)

**The Function:**

```
public function add_faculty($f_name, $f_department, $f_pic, $f_designation, $f_email, $f_doj, $f_qualification, $f_iExp_yr, $f_iExp_mth, $f_tExp_yr, $f_tExp_mth, $f_lPub, $f_iPub, $f_interest) {
    try {
        $facul_id = $this -> get_facultyID();
        $dept_id = $this -> get_DeptID($f_department);
            $db = new PDO(DB_CONN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $query = "insert into faculty (faculty_id , faculty_name , department_id , department_name ,profile_pic , designation , doj , email , highest_qualification , industrial_exp_yr ,industrial_exp_month , teaching_exp_yr , teaching_exp_month ,
    area_of_interest , national_pub , international_pub)  values (:facul_id , :f_name , :dept_id , :dept_name , :f_pic , :f_designation , :f_doj , :f_email , :f_qualification , f_iyr ,:f_imth , :ftyr , :ftmth , :finterest , :flpub , :fipub);";
        $stmt = $db -> prepare($query);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':facul_id', $facul_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_name', $f_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':dept_id', $dept_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':dept_name', $f_department, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_pic', $f_pic, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_designation', $f_designation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_doj', $f_doj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_email', $f_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_qualification', $f_qualification, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_iyr', $f_iExp_yr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_imth', $f_iExp_mth, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_tyr', $f_tExp_yr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':f_tmth', $f_tExp_mth, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':finterest', $f_interest, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':flpub', $f_lPub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':fipub', $f_iPub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt -> execute();
        if ($stmt -> rowCount() > 0) {
                $utils = new utils();
                $admin_id = $utils -> session_user_id();
                $utils -> log_admin($admin_id, "New faculty Profile Created -  " .$f_name);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    echo $ex -> getMessage();
                    //utils::log_error($ex -> getMessage());
                }

            }
```

Please help me figure out the error. I have been onto it for a few hours now. I know it might be something silly which I am not able to spot. Please let me know if you require any more details about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
    :ftyr , :ftmth
in your query but set

```
$stmt -> bindParam(':f_tyr', $f_tExp_yr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt -> bindParam(':f_tmth', $f_tExp_mth, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

in your code.

This results in that these parameters have no value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel stupid now. But Now I have  new problem , I am inserting the date as PDO::PARAM_STR , but no date is inserted. date column says 0000-00-00

Comment: Hopefully you are inserting the date in this form and not as a unix timestamp? If your php var contains e.g. `$test="2014-02-14"` this should work.

Comment: Yes that seems to the problem....

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `:` before the `f_iyr` param in your statement.

```
        $query = "insert into faculty (faculty_id , faculty_name , department_id , department_name ,profile_pic , designation , doj , email , highest_qualification , industrial_exp_yr ,industrial_exp_month , teaching_exp_yr , teaching_exp_month ,
area_of_interest , national_pub , international_pub)  values (:facul_id , :f_name , :dept_id , :dept_name , :f_pic , :f_designation , :f_doj , :f_email , :f_qualification , :f_iyr ,:f_imth , :ftyr , :ftmth , :finterest , :flpub , :fipub);";
```

in addition `:ftyr`, `:ftmth` is not set

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel stupid now. But Now I have  new problem , I am inserting the date as PDO::PARAM_STR , but no date is inserted. date column says 0000-00-00

Comment: Maybe, you have an incorrect date format(`YYYY-mm-dd`)?

Comment: yes that seems to the problem thanks...